# Can I write a library/package for R in .Net/C#?

Tags: c#, r, dll, package

I wonder whether it is possible to write a package/library for usage in R in C#. I use my own binary data store which is very low latency and high throughput and in which I store serialized value types (ints/floats/longs...) and I like to be able to access the same data in R as well. The value types in my binary store are all indexed by time but because of the particular data structure I do not see a way to currently access the whole data set in the file and particular subset from R.

The data structure is as follows:

long, float, float : where long is the date and time stamp and floats are time series data. I am happy to re-write the data structure to implement a header if that is what I need with an R package. I do not want to write the package in C or C++ but C#. Is there any way to accomplish this? Code snippets or a short description or link that describes how its done would be terrific.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible (I'm only aware of the rcpp package that can be used this way), but [here's a thread that might help you](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/232142.html). I'm aware only the [R(D) COM interface might help you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25819/The-R-Statistical-Language-and-C-NET-Foundations).

Comment: Have you looked at the [mmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmap/index.html) and [indexing](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/indexing) packages?

Comment: @rlegendi, that did not really help but thanks anyway. I tried this and R.Net and both are way too slow to send larger collections as vectors to R. That is why I look to store the collections in binaries and then load them into R. CSV or other text based formats are also too slow.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, I looked at Redis and I like what I am seeing so far, its fairly fast and it can persist the data to disk if I wish which I think memcache cannot. Memory mapping could be another solution, so, thanks for suggesting that. Let  me try it out and get back.

Comment: @Freddy Oh I see. Well, sounds like an interesting issue.

Comment: The mmap package @JoshuaUlrich mentioned has a function called struct that will let you read your binary structure directly from disk into a properly typed-list in R. This is very fast, and quite simple from an R user perspective.  ?mmap ?types and ?struct are filled with examples.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, I looked and tested mmap and the indexing packages (indexing I had to build myself from source, a package does not seem to yet exist). I have to say: AWESOME. I love what I am seeing. Mmap nicely maps my own binary files using structs. Indexing I have not performance tested yet but what Jeff Ryan showed as part of one of his presentations looked very promising. Will play with the indexing library.

Comment: @JeffR, sorry, just noticed it was actually you, THE Jeff, apologies. Love your mmap package, and will shortly take a test drive with the indexing package I built from your source code. Great work!!!

Answer (score 3):

I am looking for the same, so far I just found: https://rclr.codeplex.com/

> rClr is a package for the R statistical
>   software. The goal is to interoperate with
>   arbitrary .NET code from R without any modification to the existing
>   code. Broadly speaking, it is for .NET what rJava is for Java.

rJava:

> rJava is a simple R-to-Java interface. It is comparable to the
>   .C/.Call C interface. rJava provides a low-level bridge between R and
>   Java (via JNI). It allows to create objects, call methods and access
>   fields of Java objects from R.